# MPAndroidChart HorizontalBarChart setVisibleXRangeMaxmum not working

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image: Description]

According to the photo. I'm using `HorizontalBarChart` in `MPAndroidChart`. I just want let the chart show about 10 items in `x` direction of `HorizontalBarChart`. I `setVisibleXRangeMinimum` and `setVisibleXRangeMaxmum` but it not working. What should i do to make it work???

`Edit Jun 7 14:50`

- `initialization`

  ```
  private void initCombinedChart() {
      horizontalBarChart.setDescription("");
      horizontalBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
      horizontalBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
      horizontalBarChart.getLegend().setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
      horizontalBarChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
      horizontalBarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
      horizontalBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

      Legend legend = horizontalBarChart.getLegend();
      legend.setFormSize(8f);

      YAxis rightAxis = horizontalBarChart.getAxisRight();
      rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

      YAxis leftAxis = horizontalBarChart.getAxisLeft();
      leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
      leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
      leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
      leftAxis.setEnabled(false);

      XAxis xAxis = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
      xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
      xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
      xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);

  }
  ```
- `setData`

  ```
  private void setData() {
      ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
      ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
      DateHelper dateHelper = new DateHelper(DateHelper.FORMAT_ONLINE);

      for (OnlineCountResult.OnlineCountModel model : mDatas) {
          xVals.add(dateHelper.getDateSimpleDate(model.getBatchMinute()));
          entries.add(new BarEntry((float) model.getCountNum(), mDatas.indexOf(model)));
      }

      BarDataSet set;

      if (horizontalBarChart.getData() != null && horizontalBarChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
          set = (BarDataSet) horizontalBarChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
          set.setYVals(entries);
          horizontalBarChart.getData().setXVals(xVals);
          horizontalBarChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
          horizontalBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
      } else {
          ...

          ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
          dataSets.add(set);

          BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
          data.setValueTextSize(20f);

          horizontalBarChart.setData(data);
          horizontalBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
          horizontalBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(7);

          horizontalBarChart.animateY(1000);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you please add some code of that?

Comment: @Dhruv Sry for the delay! I've already post my code above. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Try to add `horizontalBarChart.invalidate();` and `horizontalBarChart.refreshDrawableState();` after `animateY` in your else part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are setting the dataset to chart and then you are setting its X Range instead of setting X Range before setting the dataset to chart.
You can add either following code in else part at the end:

```
horizontalBarChart.invalidate();
horizontalBarChart.refreshDrawableState();
```

Or following code in your initCombinedChart:

```
horizontalBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
horizontalBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(7);
```

**Edit 1:**
Try with `setVisibleYRangeMaximum` instead of `setVisibleXRangeMaximum`.

Comment: I've tried both of your answer, but it still not working. Y-direction in the picture was been stretched.

Comment: That means, something happen. Up-till now, nothing was stretched.

Comment: Try with `setVisibleYRangeMaximum` instead of `setVisibleXRangeMaximum`.

Comment: That working! But i can't figure out why. The X-Y direction seems mixed. I think the `horizontal-direction` should be `y-direction` and the `vertical-direction` should be `x-direction` when i initialize `HorizontalBarChart`.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer and upvote, if it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help.